# Work done by non-continuous force

Tags: forces, work, definition

How work done is really understood?
I know that $W=F\cdot d$. I am interested in the **meaning of force here** i.e.

1. Is it a continuous force applied till displacement? like the case of pulling trolley bag till displacement $d$ or
2. can it be non continuous force? Like the case of hitting pool ball with $F$, then ball covers displacement $d$

Comment: Work is defined as the line integral of force with respect to displacement, and there’s no you can’t integrate over a finite discontinuity. (You can even integrate over “infinite” discontinuities in certain contexts, but that’s a topic for another time.)

Comment: The d in the formula corresponds to the displacement of the object *while the force is acting*.

Comment: So if I throw a ball vertically to height H,  I have done work on the ball only till realising the ball? i.e. for around 1 meter of hand movement and not for the full height H covered by ball? I always thought that If I throw a ball vertically upward to height H, I am doing positive work till displacement H and gravity is doing same amount of negative work. How do you see work done by me in throwing up a ball to some height?

Comment: Yes, you do work as long as you are applying a force (just using the definition, if the force is zero, the line integral is zero). From the moment you release the ball, you are not doing any work and the ball goes straight with constant velocity (ignoring gravity). If you introduce gravity (let's neglect it while you are throwing), you are giving some (kinetic) energy to the ball by doing work, which is then converted to potential energy (increased height) and back to kinetic energy when the ball falls back.

Comment: Thank you again. Every response here is helpful. One more doubt is about when acceleration of object is involved. ***Some books suggest that integrate f.dr without accelerating the object*** like in case of finding electric potential energy of a charged particle in an electric field. I don't see that accelerating particle shuld be a problem, as it is fine in the case of throwing ball vertically upward. In doing so we accelerate the ball till releasing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula $W=Fd$ gives you the work performed by a force $F$ which is acting constantly over a particle as it moves over a distance $d$. The distance that the particle moves after the force stops does **not** figure into the calculation of work done in any way whatsoever.

Thus, when you throw a ball in the air, you apply a certain upwards force $F_\mathrm{throw}$ over a distance $d_\mathrm{throw}$ of, say about one meter, then during your interaction with the ball you perform the work $F_\mathrm{throw}d_\mathrm{throw}$. The ball then rises to a height $h$ under the action of gravity, which means that gravity performs a work $mgh$ in slowing the ball down to a stop.

With this in mind, the concept of a 'non-continuous force', like the impulsive force felt by a billiard ball when it bounces off of a hard wall, is only an approximation. In any situation like this, there is always some range of motion (often an elastic deformation of one of the bodies involved) which gets neglected, but if you want a full account of the work involved then you need to drop that approximation.

That said, though, the force involved in hitting a billiard ball with a cue is *not* in this 'non-continuous' class. The impact between the cue and the ball takes a finite (if short) time and covers a finite (if short) distance, so there is no problem in calculating the work performed.

Comment: One doubt is still remaining. It is about when acceleration of object is involved. Some ***books suggest that integrate f.dr without accelerating the object*** as in case of finding electric potential energy of a charged particle in an electric field. I don't see that accelerating particle shuld be a problem, as it is fine in the case of throwing ball vertically upward. In doing so we accelerate the ball till releasing.

Comment: The work done by a given force is independent of how big the velocities and the accelerations are – it is only a function of the force and the displacement. Beyond that, I'm not really sure what you're referring to, and if you want a more detailed commentary you should produce a specific quote from a specific source and a more detailed question.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/725153/what-is-meaning-of-work-done-without-doing-net-work-on-object-gets-stored-as-pot. This the link of question which I wanted to ask in comments.

Answer (score 1):

In any formula, the symbols must be defined and the conditions under which the formula holds should be specified.

To me, $W=\vec F\cdot \vec d$ is shorthand for "the work done by a constant force $\vec F$ along a straight path represented by a displacement $\vec d$".

To allow a more general situation, $W=\vec F\cdot \vec d$
is special case of
$$W=\int_{\mbox{specified path from A to B}} \vec F \cdot d\vec r,$$
where $\vec F$ is a force that in general varies along the specific path from A to B,
and $d\vec r$ is a tiny displacement along that specific path from A to B.
Think of dividing up the path into little directed segments and consider the average force being applied during each little segment.
*(In this formula, the object's velocity and acceleration do not matter.
Further, the force applied by other objects do not matter.
It's only about the specified force of interest and the path over which that force is applied.)*

The "force" can be the "force applied by an external object" or it could be "the net force". One should specify.

The "force" can vary continuously and it can also vary discontinuously,
or some combination of the two. (Again, think of dividing the path into little directed segments and consider the average force over that segment.)

In the example in the answer by @EmilioPisanty ,
part of the motion may involve
the **net-force** due to a variable force-vector (your hand throwing [and gravity]) for part of the path,
followed by the **net-force** due to a different force-vector (gravity alone) for the next part of the path.

---

In some situations, one might be interested in the **"work done by a conservative force"** (like a spring force or a gravitational force or an electrostatic force).

- The usual textbook storyline *(often to avoid having to reason with two minus signs)* is to consider the "force you apply" to balance the "conservative force you really want to study".
- To "balance" means that you effectively move the particle with zero acceleration [and practically at rest] so that: the "net work done is zero" (the "work done by the net fore is zero") so that the change-in-kinetic-energy [from zero kinetic energy] is zero...
- so that:
  the "work you did with your applied force" is equal to "the potential energy stored in the system" (that is, "minus the work done by the conservative force") when you moved from A to B (that is, changed the configuration from being-at-A to being-at-B).

Comment: Your post is certainly helpful. In the following link I have used some numerical values as well to ask my doubts - https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/725153/what-is-meaning-of-work-done-without-doing-net-work-on-object-gets-stored-as-pot